# My JavaScript Directory isn't linking to my HTML code correctly. Not sure why

Tags: javascript, html, css, directory

My JavaScript Directory is for some reason not linking from my html code. All the code is in the `/src` folder. the JavaScript code is in the `/src/views/js/dashboard.js` directory. My html is in `/src/public/dashboard.html`.

In my html, to link mt Js file to the HTML I wrote `<script src="../views/js/dashboard.js"></script>`.

I can't tell what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Put the code. I suspect that you import the script and in the meanwhile have code inside the script tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Umbert I don't want all of my JavaScript code in the ```<script>``` tags in the HTML file. I feel like it is unorganized.

Comment: You can't have <script src='pathresource'>Other inline code here</script>       If is this the case is there the mistake. But put the code if you want a more insight help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Main Folder is `src` and your js file inside `/src/views/js/....js` and your HTML code is here `/src/public/...html`

and You Linked like this

`<script src="../views/js/dashboard.js"></script>`

Its absolutely Right

just add `type="text/javascript"` and try again

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../views/js/dashboard.js"></script>`

If it's not working then try with only one dot

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./views/js/dashboard.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi, nothing actually changed.

Comment: can You please share a live code so I can test and easily understand what you want

Comment: Sure. Do you use repl.it?

Comment: I create a new account in repl.it what's next step

Comment: What is your username? I will invite you

Comment: ```@HirenDev```